# Great grandparent data attribute coming up undefined

Tags: jquery, attributes, parent, custom-data-attribute

I have a chart that displays data based on a state being clicked. When I want to x that state out, I want to remove that data, which I am currently doing, but I also would like to put the state corresponding to that column back into the idle state (not highlighted). Right now each state is defined with an ID of its abbreviation.

My [novice jQuery] approach is to set a data-value in the state column div that will match the div of the state so I can select that and change its fill color back to the idle state. Using the code below logs the great-grandparent data value as undefined when it should be the states abbreviation

```
var $getStateColumn = $(this).closest('div').data('value');
console.log($getStateColumn);
```

Any solution to my [very roundabout] approach?

Edit: For the sake of time I only entered in data for NY, FL, AL, GA, CA, and AK

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yurtqy87/10/

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that `$(this).closest('.pick')` gets you the underlying HTML of the div, not the HTML including the div. So you won't be able to target the div with `id = 'XX-state-column'`. To fix it you need to use `outerHTML` property which yields everything ( including the container element ).

```
 $(this).closest('.pick')[0].outerHTML;
```

By doing so you'll get the div container but not the correct one since in you click event, you again assigning the innerHTML via .html()

The easiest and less convoluted way to fix it would be introduce another attribute to each state and then extract it while click to get the id of the map container.

```
<li class="state-title-chosen univers-bold">
                        <span class="close-state" map-id="NY">X</span>New York
                    </li>

var $state_map = $(this).attr("map-id");
        $("#" + $state_map).css('fill', '');
```

Working solution : https://jsfiddle.net/yurtqy87/12/